# Is there a such thing as Informix SQL query analyzer like SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: informix

I just started a contract position with a company stuck in 1985. They're running SQL on an Informix server and access the data through a text interface that only shows one record at a time and only 14 columns for that record. In order to get anything done, you have to export the data to a text file, retrieve it from the server, and view it somehow with the text file. Then changing data consists of writing a SQL file, uploading it to the server, and running it while hoping that there are no errors. If there is an error that stops the transaction, there is nothing to indicate what or where the error is and you have to disconnect and reconnect in order to start the process over again.

I've tried Postgres and SqlDbx, but neither seem to work for the server. The server appears to be running Informix 7.30.FC6, if that means anything. I've checked IBM's website, but the descriptions of their applications are vague at best, so I can't figure which, if any of them, would work.

Comment: Informix Dynamic Server 7.30.FC6 is a 64-bit version of Informix that went out of service/support a number of years ago.  Even 7.31.FDn has been out of service for a year or more, now, and the 7.30 editions went out of service a while before that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the embedded sql tracer functions, just install the free OpenAdminTool web interface (its like the phpmyadmin of Informix), and go the the "SQL Trace" menu. You will get graphic query plans etc.

I doubt it will work with Informix version 7, so you should probably think about migrating from 7 to the IDS 11.70 Innovator-C version. It's a 2GB ram limited edition, but free if you do not redistribute it. Backwards compatibility is very good with informix.

Another option is to use SeverStudio (not free), and it only supports Query Plans, not actual query execution trace as far as I know.

Comment: +1 on Server Studio.  I've also had the misfortune to work with Informix and Server Studio made a lot of painful tasks a bit more reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

IBM make available a tool called IBM Data Studio, which connects to an IDS instance and does most of the stuff you would expect in Sql Server Studio Manager or the Oracle equivalent. I believe it's a free download (although, as usual, there's a much better paid-for version)

I've recently used it with some success, but to be honest I found myself using the text interface DBAccess tool much more frequently once I had got used to it, because it generally was much faster to use.